# Django - Use class as inline in both parent and parent of parent

Tags: django, django-admin, inline, models

I have three class in my code. Exam, Question and QuestionResource. QuestionResource is a file and has a foreign key to Question.Also Question has a foreign key to Exam. Currently Question is included as inline in Exam's admin view. However it is seperately registered in the admin so I can both add question using its own admin or using the inline-view in Exam admin view.

The problem is I want to be able to add QuestionResource both when I'm editing the Exam and when I'm editing the Question. But when I try to add QuestionResource as inline of Exam it errors with:

> 'exams.QuestionResource' has no ForeignKey to 'exams.Exam'.

Ofcourse I can add a foreign-key to Exam in the QuestionResource model but since it's always must be equal to QuestionResource.Question.Exam I don't think it's the right way to do it. Also I don't want to set the Exam when I'm adding Resource in Question admin-view.(Ofcourse I must set the question when I'm editing the Exam admin-view.)

Does django support something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't support this (yet) but [django-nested-inline](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline) can do the job.

Comment: Thanks, does the job.